# How to update row which have unique id in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table which has a field of `customer_number`, some numbers repeat many times but I want to get only that number which is unique in filed.

```
public function set_unique()
{
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    if($e == 1)
    {   
        $one = $this->db->get('calls_details');
        foreach($one->result() as $data) {
            $two = $this->db->where('Customer_Number', $data->Customer_Number)
                            ->get('calls_details');
            if($two->num_rows() == 1) {
                foreach($two->result() as $data2) {
                   $three = $this->db->where('Customer_Number', $data2->Customer_Number)
                                        ->update('calls_details', ['unique_id'=>1]);

                }
            }
          }    
       }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to update the field unique_data = 1 which row has unique customer_number

Comment: You need another id as unique or `autoincrement` by which you can easily change one specific record. Regarding your `Customer_number` as its repeated so updates should be based on this id.

Comment: I have a unique id field but I want to get all Customer_Number which is unique in all tabe

Comment: As you said in your questions that some numbers repeat many times. 

Any way, you need to do as I am going to answer.

Comment: SELECT customer_number FROM `calls_details` where customer_number IN (select customer_number from calls_details group by customer_number HAVING count(customer_number) = 1); Use this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// defining array in which we get form values
$dataDB = ['first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
           'second_name' => $this->input->post('second_name'),
           'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            ];

// load model
$this->load->model('Customer');

//set record id, which we need to be updated
$this->Customer->id = $uniqueCustomerIDNumber;

//save record
$this->Customer->save();
```

Comment: I've edited my question with my code I hope you'll understand what I want to do.

Comment: @TarunBhardwaj well, your code has a lot of confusion and not much clear. secondly after foreach i think you should use `#data2->customer_number` instead of '$data->customer_number'

Comment: @TarunBhardwaj ok can you share relevant files and db table if possible let me know I can share my emil.

Comment: hmmmmm ok then share the parameters you are passing in request and I will try to update code/answer

Comment: @TarunBhardwaj yup sure. its `ping@naveedramzan.com`